# Prepend a digit to the beginning of a field

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I need to add a "0" before a integer field in a MYSQL table. How do I update those fields so they have a ) added to them? Thanks.

Comment: BTW when you add something to the beginning of something it is called **prepending**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't unless you change the column type to string. However you can add the zero when reading the field:

```
SELECT CONCAT( '0', int_col ) FROM ....
```

Comment: thank you! this was perfect... the column was actually of type varchar. So I did an: "update table set field = CONCAT('0', field) where blah. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **format** the output of all integer values in one column to a **fixed column size**, say 5, with **leading zeroes** for small numbers, use an ALTER TABLE statement like:

```
ALTER TABLE table MODIFY `col` INT(5) ZEROFILL;
```

Refer to [MySQL 5.1 Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-types.htmlhttp://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-types.html).